# How to to give the link for my all array elements without giving the index of my array elements individually?

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

```
<div *ngFor="let offers1 of offers1">{{offers1}}</div>
```

am having this in my HTML code.

```
offers1: any= [
    'LED TVs',
    'QLED TVs',
    'OLED TVs',
    '4K Ultra HD TVs',
    'Smart TVs',
    'Full HD TVs',
    'HD Ready TVs',
    'Large Screens',
    'Medium Screens',
    'Small Screens',
    'TV Accessories',
    'TV Wall Mount Stands',
    'Cables & Connectors',
    'Media Streaming Devices'
];
```

'having this array in my TS file.
I need each of my array elements to take me to the new screen .So I need to give the link for my all array elements without giving the index of my array elements individually.
In future I will make to change my array elements .so I need the stable content for giving links.

Thanks in advance.'

Comment: Hi, have you tried using array of objects. For Ex: offers1: any = [{"link": "", "name": "LED TVs"}]

Comment: @Ritu yeah ,I tried this but its not worked for my code.

Comment: Please, post the code here, so that it will be easy to find out the issue

Comment: Above represent my code when am calling array{offers1} in my div it will loading the page with array element...I need to click the elements like LED it will go to LED page..Thats what i need .am not able to put the href tag for offers1 because it got more than one element .

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this. Inside your component TS:

```
links = [
        { title: 'LED TVs', link: 'led'},
        { title: 'QLED TVs', link: 'qled'},
        { title: 'OLED TVs', link: 'oled'}
    ];
```

which works with the following HTML

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <li *ngFor="let link of links" class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active"
                [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="link.link" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">
          {{link.title}}
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

where as 'link' element inside links array of component typescript refers to -routing.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AllTVComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'led', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'led', component: LedComponent },
      { path: 'qled', component: QLedComponent },
      { path: 'oled', component: OLedComponent }
    ]
  },
  
];
```

This will let your app navigate to respective components intended to.
Happy coding!